# Windows 10: make drive letter unavailable

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-10, drive-letter

On my Windows 10 system I have the following drive letters assigned:

- C:\ SSD (The system drive)

  D:\ HDD (has junction from C:\Users)

  E:\ Blu-Ray optical drive

  F:\ DVD optical drive

  G:\ external HDD

  I:\ through L:\ for card reader

Notice that H:\ is missing, which is by design. I do not want to use H: as a drive letter, as it causes problems with Radeon Settings. However, whenever I plug something in that has never been assigned a drive letter, the system assigns H:. Is there any way to get Windows 10 to never assign this drive letter?
I seem to remember a window in XP or 7 where you could uncheck certain drive letters, thereby making them unavailable, but I cannot find this in Windows 10 (and it may have been solely for the availability of network drive letters). Google searches have turned up some references to Disk Management, but that only allows one to remove a drive letter already assigned to a device. I also found a reference here on Superuser to "mountvol" but that doesn't seem to fit the bill either.
**Edit:**Here's a [link](https://community.amd.com/thread/199858) to the problem-report opened on AMD's website. Their "solutions" aren't exactly helpful.

Comment: Have you looked over http://www.thewindowsclub.com/show-hide-a-drive-in-windows and in the **Hide Drive using Windows Registry** section see if that solution will work for your need?

Comment: You should aim to fix the real problem, the "Radeon Settings" should care which drive letters you have.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, the problem appears to be a bug in the Radeon Settings program. As far as I know it has been reported to AMD, but they appear to be in no hurry to fix it. They may not even be able to reproduce it. I did not see it until installing Windows 10 and never saw it in Windows 7.

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT, the tools presented on that site only hide the drive letter (except for the registry fix, which didn't work on my Windows 10 machine), they don't prevent the system from assigning that drive letter when it sees a new drive and that drive letter is the next available.

Comment: I don't have time to do a bunch of research on this now but there are many developers on here so maybe one of them know of a way and will give you some suggestions. I think the vendor needs to provide a solution to this issue if it's compatible with that OS rather than trying to make the Windows OS behave to accommodate what's listed as compatible otherwise with that OS. A drive mapping letter messing with settings of a Graphics Card is an issue with the graphics card, many companies use the "H" drive as the Home directory with logon scripts... This is a Strange issue I've not run into yet.